# Plot two columns of data, one with reversed y-scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a data frame with 3 columns:

```
n value1 value2
1  2       8      
2  4       6
3  6       4
4  8       2
```

I want to plot them in the following manner. For each n make one bar, on positive y scale for value1 and on reversed y scale for value2:

[image: Example of what I want]

This should be faceting compatible (since there are actually 2 more columns).

This is what I managed so far

```
p = data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(n), y = value1),stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(n), y = value2),stat="identity",position="dodge") + scale_y_reverse() +      
  facet_grid(A ~ B) +
  ylab("value 1/2") +
  xlab("number")    
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(n))) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value1, fill = "Value 1")) +
  geom_col(aes(y = -value2, fill = "Value 2")) +  
  ylab("value 1/2") +
  xlab("number")
```

Comment: You can use add a layer of `scale_y_continuous` to adjust the y axis breaks / labels and a layer of `scale_fill_manual` to adjust the fill colors of the bars.

Comment: This works, thanks. But then another question arises: how to make custom labels for y axis ticks? And apply different colours?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot plot a subset of values on a secondary y-axis in ggplot2, as it opens a floodgate for misleading visualizations. The secondary y-axis option in ggplot2 allows you to display a secondary y-axis *conditionally on it being a linear transformation of the primary*.

However, your case is simple: The downwards bars are simply your value2 multipled by -1:

```
df %>% mutate(value2=value2*-1) %>% gather(stat, val, value1, value2) %>% ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(n), y=val, fill=stat)) + geom_col()
```